# Loop in js to set the default value of a DropDown list.Not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have used the following piece of code to set defailt value of a DropDownn List in Sharepoint List form

```
for ( var i = 0; i < getField('select','County').options.length; i++ ) {
if ( getField('select','County').options[i].text == "New County" ) {
getField('select','County').options[i].selected = true;
}
}
```

The loop works fine on all other browser except IE8, how can i solve this issue

i get the error in IE8 as:

```
options is null or not an object
```

EDIT:

```
function getField(fieldType,fieldTitle) 
 {     
   var docTags = document.getElementsByTagName(fieldType);     
   for (var i=0; i < docTags.length; i++)
    {         
      if (docTags[i].title == fieldTitle)
      { 
         return docTags[i]; 
      }     
    } 
 }
```

Comment: This really depends on the implementation of getField().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above exception was not because of IE8 but because in sharepoint, when list values in select goes above 20 the control is rendered as `input` and not `select`.

When i tried in IE9 i had only few values in select and on server it was IE8 and had many values in the list.